# Error when creating a user in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

This looks like is should be a simple command run described [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/masking-passwords.html) which shows a simple example:

```
./artemis user add --username guest --password guest --role admin
```

But it gives an error:

```
Found unexpected parameters: [--username, guest]
```

What am I missing here? I'm in the broker directory (/var/lib/broker1/bin)

What could I have wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter name `--username` is invalid. You should use `--user` instead.

For what it's worth you can see the valid parameters by running the `help` command, e.g.:

```
./artemis help user add
```

Here's the output of that command:

```
NAME
        artemis user add - Add a new user

SYNOPSIS
        artemis user add [--entry <entry>] [--password <password>] [--plaintext]
                [--role <role>] [--silent] [--user <username>] [--verbose]

OPTIONS
        --entry <entry>
            The appConfigurationEntry (default: activemq)

        --password <password>
            the password (Default: input)

        --plaintext
            using plaintext (Default false)

        --role <role>
            user's role(s), comma separated

        --silent
            It will disable all the inputs, and it would make a best guess for
            any required input

        --user <username>
            The user name (Default: input)

        --verbose
            Adds more information on the execution
```

I've [committed a change](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/commit/fb60795b59f24da9e01cade972721da1dda90803) to fix the documentation.